# how to inherit and display some fields of view odoo 11

Tags: xml, odoo-11

I want to inherit the Hr.employee form ,
but I want to display just some fields
I do not want to see all the fields in my form

```
       <record id="action_emmployee_module" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Manager</field>
            <field name="res_model">hr.employee</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>  
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
                    Add employee
                </p>
            </field>
        </record>

   <record model="ir.ui.view" id="emmployee_module_form_view">
            <field name="name">employee.form</field>
            <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
            <field name="priority">20</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="  address_id  "/>
                <field name=" work_email "/>
               <field name="departement_id"/>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="emmployee_module_form_view">
        <field name="name">employee.form</field>
        <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
        <field name="priority">20</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <xpath expr="." position="replace">
            <field name="  address_id  "/>
            <field name=" work_email "/>
           <field name="departement_id"/>
          </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

This will change the view of employee form view everywhere.

Comment: thank you for your answer but it does not show anything if I make your proposal
i want to display just some fields from the view not all inherit in my new form

Comment: Even after applying this if you are not getting as expected then you must reduce the priority to a lower value like priority 2 or 3 then it should work.